# Simpson's 3/8 Rule Error

Tags: matlab

```
%Simpson's 3/8 rule
b=3;
a=0;
x=1;
y(x) = (exp(x)*sin(x)) /( 1 + x^2); 
I=((b-a)/8)*(y(a)+3*y((2*a+b)/3)+3*((a+2*b)/3)+y(b));
disp(I);
```

In this code i am simply trying to use Simpson's 3/8 rule but when i try to test it. I get this error:

```
Attempted to access y(0); index must be a positive integer or
logical.

Error in simpson38 (line 5)
I=((b-a)/8)*(y(a)+3*y((2*a+b)/3)+3*((a+2*b)/3)+y(b));
```

So what should i do to fix this? Thanks from now.

Comment: I=((b-a)/8)*(y(a)+3*y((2*a+b)/3)+3*y((a+2*b)/3)+y(b)); You were missing a y in the third term. This might just be an edit to your question.

Comment: Thanks, i corrected it. But it didn't help to resolve this problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are trying to define a function `y(x)`, then you need to create an anonymous function:

```
y = @(x) (exp(x)*sin(x)) / (1 + x^2);
```

In your code, `y(x) = ...` where `x=1` just sets element 1 of `y`, hence creating a scalar `y`.